# difference between affectation and hypocrisy?

Tags: differences

Here are the definitions of the two words:

- **Hypocrisy:** the practice of claiming to have moral standards or beliefs to which one's own behavior does not conform; pretense.
- **Affectation:** behavior, speech, or writing that is artificial and designed to impress.

However, I'm not sure about the difference between the usage/connotation of these two words? Is there any example where you would use *hypocrisy* instead of *affectation* or the other way round?

Comment: Welcome: Hypocrisy is saying one thing and doing another. Affectation is putting on a show.   They are different. Could you explain why you think they are the same? Thanks.

Comment: well, in my eyes they are both a kind of pretence and i couldn't make out the difference. i still think that these two words are interchangeable in some cases. i've found this example for instance:

There was no hypocrisy in the tears of the empress.
http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/hypocrisy

now i argue that your definition '(not) putting on a show' could also work here.
but quasimods explanation was very useful.
by the way, i dont really see why this posting is off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

They are similar, but have very different connotations. Affectation is behavior designed to impress other people, while hypocrisy is intended to deceive them.

[Samuel Johnson](http://www.samueljohnson.com/affectat.html) (1709-1784) said:

"Hypocrisy is the necessary burden of villainy, affectation part of the chosen trappings of folly; the one completes a villain, the other only finishes a fop. Contempt is the proper punishment of affectation, and detestation the just consequence of hypocrisy."